# $y=1+x$, $x \in[-1,4]$ find integral using definition.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Dividing given interval into $n$ equal parts and for every interval taking $\epsilon$ as an midpoint of an interval find integral sum of a function and compute it.

$y=1+x$, $x \in[-1,4]$

$P$ is given splitting of an inteval.

$\sigma(P,\epsilon)$ = $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\epsilon)\triangle x_i$

Because length of an interval is $5$

$\triangle x_i=\frac{5}{n}$ and $\epsilon_i= \frac{x_{i+1}-x_i}{2}$

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+\epsilon_i)\triangle x_i=\sum_{}(1+\frac{10}{n}){\frac{5}{n}}$ which doesn't given answer in the book. Answer is $12.5.$

Comment: Shouldn't there be $+$ instead of $-$ in $\varepsilon_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\epsilon_i=\frac{x_{i}+x_{i+1}}{2}=\frac12\left(-1+5\frac i n-1+5\frac {i+1} n\right)=-1+\frac 5 2\frac{2i+1}n \implies f(\epsilon_i)=\frac 5 2\frac{2i+1}n$$

and therefore

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac52\frac{2i+1}n\triangle x_i=\frac{25}{2n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2i+1)=\frac {25}{ 2n^2}n^2=\frac {25}{ 2}$$

Comment: How $\epsilon_i=-1+5\frac{i}{n}$ ?

Comment: @unit1991 I'm indicating indeed the left point, I fix that.

Comment: I am not sure how $-1 + 5\frac{i}{n}$ gives left endpoint can you please explain that part?

Comment: @unit1991 By dividing the interval $[-1,4]$ in $n$ parts the division points are $-1$, $-1+\frac 5 n$, $-1+\frac{5\cdot 2}n$, $\ldots$ that is $-1+\frac{5\cdot i}n$ with $i=0,\ldots,n-1$. And then $\epsilon_i= \frac{x_{i+1}+x_i}{2}$.